# PHP setcookie only intermittently works (version compatibility?)

Tags: php, setcookie

I am currently running 2 versions of PHP. My local (test) server has 5.3.5, while my remote (live) server has 5.2.4. This has caused a few compatibility issues in the past, but I've always been able to fix them pretty easily. Soon my remote server will be upgraded, so it won't cause too many more issues, but in the mean time I still have to provide solutions for these stupid compatibility issues. Will someone please take a look at my code below and let me know if they spot any issues for a 5.2.4 PHP build?

```
function _cookie($name, $value) {
    $expire = strtotime('+1 month');
    $old_expire = strtotime('last day of next month');

    setcookie(
        $name,
        $value,
        $expire
    );
    var_dump($name, $value, $expire, $old_expire);
}

$date = date(
    'Y-m-d H:i:s',
    filemtime($file)
);
_cookie('user', 'bob');//works
_cookie('up2date', $date);//does not
```

I originally had 'last day of next month' as my cookie expiration date, which is why its still in the `var_dump` list. However, that string was returning false on the remote server causing cookies to expire at the end of the session. Even though it returned false, it would still set the "user" cookie and I was able to view it in the browser. It would not, however, set the "up2date" cookie. I thought this was odd, but figured it had something to do with the `strtotime` function returning false. So I tried fixing that first. After consulting the PHP manual I determined that the string I was using was only available on 5.3. There, problem confirmed, easy fix. I replaced it with the '+1 month' string, which I know will work on 5.2. Success, my "user" cookie now expires as it should. Except I still dont have an "up2date" cookie. `var_dump` proves that the function is being called to set it and has all the correct parameters but it isn't setting the second cookie. I wouldn't be as frustrated if it just didn't work at all. That would at least tell me that I was doing something wrong and I could weedle it out. But for it to tease me like this... What am I missing? Does anyone have any ideas?

var_dump results:

```
//Local server
string(4) "user"
string(3) "bob"
int(1337797496)
int(1338488696)

string(7) "up2date"
string(19) "2012-04-20 10:52:09"
int(1337797496)
int(1338488696)

//Remote server
string(4) "user"
string(3) "bob"
int(1337795061)
bool(false)

string(7) "up2date"
string(19) "2012-04-23 09:14:19"
int(1337795061)
bool(false)
```

Comment: what if you change 'up2date' to 'update' ? I've never successfully used numerals part-way through variable names

Comment: Didn't help. Besides, it works on the local one (same browser, same machine), and has worked in the past. It was only recently when I changed it to use `strtotime` that it stopped working. I would just change it back, but if it works for one, why not both?

Comment: is it a possible permission issue with the file being sent to filemtime()?  try a chmod on that $file before filemtime() before reading the filemtime()

Comment: @b_dubb that variable is the cookie value, not the expiration. I just found this link on Google, what if you replace your `last day of next month` with these functions? http://ullu.wordpress.com/2007/02/28/find-last-day-of-the-month-in-php/

Comment: @b_dubb: Nice thought, but no. I changed it all the way "777", dumped cache and cookies and tried again. Still won't set.

Comment: @Set Sail Media: Would you mind posting those functions? My work doesn't like blog websites and systematically blocks them so I'm unable to view it.

Comment: @showerhead **EDIT** Damn proxy sites. What it suggests is `date('Y-m-d',strtotime('-1 second',strtotime('+1 month',strtotime(date('m').'/01/'.date('Y').' 00:00:00'))));`

Comment: @DaveRandom: Shoulda flagged that one NSFW -.- First thing to pop up was "Website Unblocker". Wonder how many red flags that will raise...

Comment: Apologies, I though it would just take you the site through the proxy, but they seem to referer-check. I have posted the code it linked to.

Comment: It's a pretty silly suggestion actually, when you could just do `strtotime("+2 months -".date('n')." days")`

Comment: @DaveRandom: Its also the wrong format for a cookie expiration, and doesn't really pertain to the question. My cookie expiration could be anything really as the people who use it will reset it almost every day anyways. The reason I give it a month is just in case. My main issue is that it only works for one of the two cookies I'm trying to set. The other just never gets set.

Comment: @DaveRandom: Also, both give different values anyways. The date solution you gave me first gives the end of the current month, while your strtotime solution gives June 19 (~+2 months)

Comment: I just realised my solution should have used `date('j')` instead of `date('n')`. But it's somewhat besides the point since it's not that relevant to the question - back *on* the point, what happens if you reverse the order of the `_cookie()` calls? Does the problem now move to the `user` cookie?

Comment: just commented it out, and no, that didn't make a difference :(

Comment: Try 60*60*24*28 instead of +1 month

Comment: @DavidBélanger: That is what I originally had it working with. So I know that works, but doesn't answer why the strtotime solution would work for one and not the other.

Comment: Maybe because the server is configured diffrently... timezone, etc.

Comment: @DaveRandom: My apologies, you hit something there. This code is actually in a class and each cookie was called in a different function. I moved the setcookie for up2date into the same function as user and it works. So it has something to do with the separation... Now I wonder why it would do this when it will still dump the correct parameters after apparently throwing no errors while trying to set it... That cookie function is verbatim, its just the calls that I made generic.

Comment: @DavidBélanger: Its not the servers, both servers save the user cookie with no problem using the same code. Only the local server saves the up2date cookie.

Comment: @DaveRandom: That helped me figure it out. Stupid me. I had output before I called the second cookie so it was failing to set it. Thanks for all your help! If you post this as your solution I'll award you the answer as it led me to the correct solution.

Comment: Hang on a minute - isn't the problem (ironically) the fact that you are calling `var_dump()`? In the first call, you can set the cookie because the headers have not been sent, but by the second call you output something in the first, so it won't work.

Comment: Oh, you figured that out, lol

Comment: It wasn't that I was calling the var_dump, that was merely for testing why it wasn't working. It was just its location in the script. I was using it to get a URL. If the "up2date" cookie wasn't set, it would load a changelog, otherwise it would load the default page. I had called the function that set it after content was already displayed on the page. So I just moved it to the beginning, set it as a variable, and used the variable instead of calling the function directly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to DaveRandom. He deserves the credit here and if he adds his answer I'll switch my accepted to his. I just added this answer so I don't have any unanswered questions.

**The Solution:** I had output before I called the second cookie so it was failing to set it. I just moved where I set the cookie.

Thank you all for your suggestions and time!